# Not able to install mysql workbench on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-16.04

while installing MYSQL workbench from software center, the system shutdown due to a power cut.
After I powered it back up, when I try to install the workbench again, it does not install and when I try to install it from command line using

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

I get following error.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: mysql-workbench :
>   Depends: libgdal.so.1-1.11.3 Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.8.0) but it is
>   not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
>   broken packages.

Please help to install it on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is technically not the right place to ask this, but you could use sudo apt-get install -f or sudo dpkg --configure -a. If that does not work reboot the system and try going to recovery mode and fix broken packages, provided your internet works without the system logging in. If that does not work download and install libgdal.so from its repo manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list held packages : apt-mark showhold
then 
get them out of held state: apt-mark unhold

then remove them. then try your main install again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. I was not able to install it using apt-get, but I had no problem doing so with the .deb file:

1. Go to [mysql-workbench download site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
2. Select Platform > Ubuntu Linux > Download
3. No thanks, just start my download.
4. Open the deb file downloaded
5. Click Install

I hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

1. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/
   Download apt repository

Select “No thanks, just start my download“

2)install  `sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb`

3)During the installation, we will be prompted by dialog box,click ‘OK’ to continue MySQL Workbench installation.

4)update apt

`sudo apt update`

5)install workbench

`sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community`

6)To launch run `mysql-workbench`

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu 19

1)I had to preceding it on Ubuntu 19 also install manually a library libzip
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb.html

2) then manually selecting on download page deb package for mysql workbench
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

then install deb packages via standard apt installer in Downloads dir

`sudo apt install ./libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb`

and downloaded workbench deb package

`sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb`